# crystal reports filter details

Tags: filter, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I use section expert - supress and try to filter what data is displayed in the report.

What I want should be simple:

```
{InspectionReport.EquipmentStatus}="Approved"
```

But it seems the data don't get passed through, still all data is displayed, etc `Failed` and `Working on` gets in the report.

Should I use some other method?

Comment: Where did you write that code in crystal reports

Comment: right click section 3(Details) - Section Expert - markSuppress(No Drill-Down) and click x+2 for editing formula

Comment: It us correct right... you are supressing approved so failed and working will be displayed.... what are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: eg I want to see all data that is not Approved, but I seem to get all data whatever I do.

Comment: If you want to see all data that is not approved then what you are doing is correct.... check the name approved exists in database or not

Comment: Why aren't you using a record-selection formula?

Comment: Don't know how to do it. 

I fixed the problem, had to do the sorting one section over hte one I was in.